# Is it possible to get all Namespaces from the DataStore with objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, namespaces, datastore, objectify

How can I get a list of all namespaces from the GAE datastore using objectify?

I have found the implementation by google in [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/metadataqueries):

```
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entities;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query;


void printAllNamespaces(DatastoreService ds, PrintWriter writer) {

  Query q = new Query(Entities.NAMESPACE_METADATA_KIND);

  for (Entity e : ds.prepare(q).asIterable()) {
    // A nonzero numeric id denotes the default namespace;
    // see Namespace Queries, below
    if (e.getKey().getId() != 0) {
      writer.println("<default>");
    } else {
      writer.println(e.getKey().getName());
    }
  }
```

I couldn't find any way to use it with objectify .
Does anyone knows such a way? or is it not yet implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can't be done for now with the objectify framework.
a discussion was opened in [google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/objectify-appengine/ZqryTKFLt6E)